# Softmax activation function output (with Tanh)

Tags: neural-network, supervised-learning, softmax, activation-function

I am working on an **MLP-neural network** using supervised learning.

For the hidden layers I am using Tanh `(-1,1)` and for the output layer Softmax (which gives the probability distribution btw 0 and 1.

As I am working with supervised learning should my target output be between `0` and `1`, or `-1` and `1` (because of the Tanh function), or does it not matter?

Thanks!

Comment: The targets depend on the task (classification or regression) and the loss function, You should include more information.

Comment: It is a classification problem (2 classes and multi-classes - separate problems). The loss funtions is MSE (quadratic). Thanks

Comment: You should use categorical cross-entropy for softmax classification, and in this case the labels have to be one-hot encoded. MSE is not a classification loss.

Comment: Right! But if I use Mse and tanh and softmax. What should be my target output. Is there a problem to use -1 and 1 or 0 and 1?

Comment: The hidden layer activation is irrelevant, one hot encoding means the targets are vectors of binary 0/1 values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with however I use both (one simulation -1 and 1 and another 0 and 1) and the results are the same (only the loss function had another value) but then I can adjust the error tolerance. But speaking about the probability it was the same. How can I explain that?